# How to trigger element rotation on button click? (AngularJS/Ionic)

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, ionic-framework

I'm attempting to build an app with Ionic framework and Angular, but everything I try to make a smooth rotation animation on a div element isn't working properly. I need it to happen every time I click a button. The div element is separate from the button. I would like it to rotate 360 degrees and be repeatable.

I don't really have any code for you guys because I don't know how to do this! Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) combined with CSS3 [transform:rotate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) from 0-360 degrees is one approach. Here is a working example:

http://play.ionic.io/app/7ab32156c805

css

```
#box {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.spin {
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Spin Click Demo</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <div id="box" ng-class="divClass"></div>
        <button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="divClass='spin'">Spin</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

js

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
```

Comment: Thank you! Had to edit it a bit because "$ is not defined", but instead using ng-class worked. Animation was good.

Comment: excellent point, I removed jQuery and the controller code in favor of [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) in the answer